# Whenever I go onto Chrome, all my extensions, and preferences are lost? Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: google-chrome

When I go onto Chrome, an alert comes up that says something along the lines of "Your preferences could not be saved." All my extensions are lost and my settings are back to default. How do I get it back to normal? Do I have to uninstall/reinstall Chrome? If I do, will all my bookmarks be deleted?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, file a bug on chromium at crbug.com to get better help. SO is not the place for this.

Comment: What stackexchange network is a appropriate to post this question on by the way?

Comment: Make sure you enable sync and export your bookmarks. Then you can uninstall/reinstall without losing them.

Comment: @David What version of chrome do you use ?

Comment: @HackToHell I have the latest version: 17.0.963.83

Comment: @abraham How do I do that??

Comment: @David http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall chrome completely, then run the reg file specified [here](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=111899), then re-install and sync your [profile with google](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139).

Comment: I filed a bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119873 

But I don't know how to do the things they are asking in that link you gave me.

Comment: @David Google guys might help you ...

Comment: The reg file link is broken.

Comment: yeah, hopefully Google fixes it soon.